# Class function doesn't show the value passed in

Tags: python

My function doesn't show the input number for number_served:

```
class Restaurant():

    def __init__(self, name, cuisine):
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine
        self.number_served = 0

    def describe_rest(self):
        print("Welcome to " + self.name.title() + "!")
        print("We serve the best " + self.cuisine.title() + " food!")

    def open_rest(self):
        print(self.name.upper() + " is OPEN now!")

    def set_number_served(self, number_served):
        print("We have served " + str(self.number_served)
         + " customers today.")

    def increment_number_served(self, additional_served):
        print("We have served " + str(self.number_served) 
        + str(self.additional_served) + " customers today.")


restaurant = Restaurant('gamja', 'korean')

print("\n")
restaurant.describe_rest()
print("\n")
restaurant.open_rest()

restaurant.set_number_served(1000)
```

At the last line, `restaurant.set_number_served(1000)`, I get "We have served 0 customers today." instead of 1000. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to set the instance variable in that routine.  Simply add a line to do that.

```
def set_number_served(self, number_served):
    self.number_served = number_served
    print("We have served " + str(self.number_served)
     + " customers today.")
```